dotnet dev-certs https --trust runtime error
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
throw an error
There was an error exporting the HTTPS developer certificate to a file.
Any help much appreciated?

Which OS you are using ? Linux, Macos or Windows ? And we also need detailed error message about this issue.

@Jason Pan Windows machine

I found the solution, unfortunately it was an internal system check and not related to ASPNET certificates. The system was looking for a existing folder in %APP_DATA% > Roaming
